# Encrypting Passwords to match stored encrypted passwords.

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I started working on a project which had a lot of code already in place.  It is a Ruby on Rail application that uses Devise for user authentication.  One of the requirements of the application is that when a user changes their password, they are not allowed to use the same password as the last three passwords they previously used.  To acomplish this, there is a table that contains a history of passwords for a given user.  These passwords are copies of the encrypted passwords that existed prior to any password change on the user.

Here is where the problem comes in.  We have a password change form that collects the new password for a given user.  I need to be able to take the new password and encrypt it so that I can match the encrypted value of the new password against encrypted values of the old passwords in history.

Technical Stuff
Rails version 3.0.9
Devise version 1.3.4
Using standard BCrypt with Devise.  bcrypt_ruby version 2.1.4

To do this we are overrriding the reset_password method supported by Devise.  This allows us to introduce our own method, has_repeated_password in the user controller.

The version of has_repeated_password I started with is below:

```
  def has_repeated_password?
    return false if self.new_record? || self.version == 1
    histories = self.versions.find(:all, :order => 'version DESC', :limit => 3)

    histories.detect do |history|
      history.encrypted_password == self.class.encryptor_class.digest(self.password, self.class.stretches, history.password_salt, self.class.pepper)
    end
  end
```

The problem here is that the encryptor class is never defined, causing an error every time this routine runs.  Even through there are many examples that claim this works, I cannot get it to work when Devise is using the default encryption.

A second attempt at this is the following code:

```
  def has_repeated_password?<br>
    return false if self.new_record? || self.version == 1
    histories = self.versions.find(:all, :order => 'version DESC', :limit => 3)

    histories.detect do |history|
      pwd = self.password_digest(self.password)
      history.encrypted_password == pwd
    end
  end
```

In this case, I never get a password that matches any of the stored passwords, even though I have verified that the password in the database is what I expect.

I have been trying to dig through the Devise code to see what I can find there.  I know that the autentication has to do this somehow when it matches passwords collected from users against the stored password.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I think I found a solution to my own problem.  The key sticking point of this was that I was trying to get an encrypted password that was not part of the user model (any more) tied to Devise.  This solution does assume that Devise will be using Bcrypt as the standard encryption tool (can't remember which version of Devise made the move).  Bcrypt/Devise actually buries the salt for the password in the encrypted password.  If you have the salt and the pepper, you can get the same password to generate the same encrypted value.

So here is the updated code for the routine refernced above:

```
  def has_repeated_password?
    return false if self.new_record? || self.version == 1

    histories = self.versions.find(:all, :order => 'version DESC', :limit => 3)
    histories.detect do |history|
      bcrypt   = ::BCrypt::Password.new(history.encrypted_password)
      password = ::BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret("#{self.password}#{self.class.pepper}", bcrypt.salt)
      password == history.encrypted_password
    end
  end
```

The key here is that the Bcyrpt object has to be created with an existing encrypted password using the same salt that generated the original password.  That is accomplished by giving it my stored historical encrypted password (history.encrypted_password).  One of the other key elements is that both the history passwords and the proposed new password use the same pepper, which is managed by Devise.  So by using the Engne.has_secret call with the intended new password, it can be compared with the history password.

I had to move the bcrypt code into here because all the password methods supported by Devise assume that you want to act on the user password of the current user object.

Comment: It is more correct to use `p = BCrypt::Password.new(history.encrypted_password)` and then `p == password`. `BCrypt::Password` class has `==` operator defined.